# BjyAuthorize with ZfcUser and Doctrine - managing user_role_linker

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zfcuser, bjyauthorize

I have implemented BjyAuthorize with ZfcUser and Doctrine and can successfully set up the roles and linked them to `user_id` in the `user_role_linker` table.  Next I want to add a simple admin panel to get, add and remove users from the `user_role_linker` table.

I can see certain methods available based on the currently logged in identity e.g. `getIdentityRoles()` but how is it possible to get /add / remove roles for any user?

This is clearly possible with MySQL direct to the table but presumably it's achievable by a BjyAuthorize service?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out - to add a role the just use the $user->addRole() method in the zfcUser entity provided by bjyAuthorize:

```
$addRole = //id of role to add
$roleRepo = $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\Role');
$roleResult = $roleRepo->findOneBy(['id' => $addRole]);
$user->addRole($roleResult);
```

This works fine, but I can't see how it is possible to delete a role?